# top div wont change background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is what I trying to do:
When I type into the `input` field I want the top level `div.container-fluid` to change colors. Right now I can only get the `.xdiv` area to change but not any divs that are higher than that.
Here is my code:

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').keypress(function () { 
            var $this = $(this),
                $div = $(this).parent();
            if ($this.val().length > 0) {
                $div.addClass("hasContent");
            } else {
                $div.removeClass("hasContent");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .container-fluid.hasContent { background-color: red }
        </style>    

<div class="container-fluid linear-Algebra" id="{{id}}">        
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">                        
            <div class="row-fluid">                             
                <div class="span8 grid-layout"> 
                    <legend>Grid Layout:</legend>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <div class="xdiv">
                            <label>x:</label>                                   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 offset1">
                        <div class="ydiv">  
                            <label>y:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>                          
                <div class="span3">
                    <legend>Options:</legend>
                    <div class="btngroup">
                        <label class="checkbox" class="cbl">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <label>Actions:</label> 
                    <div class="btngroup">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>                                  
        </div>              
    </div>                              
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the input field supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/yC28X/)

CHANGE THIS

```
$div = $(this).parent();
```

TO

```
$div = $(this).parents('.container-fluid');
```

`parents('.container-fluid')` find the parent with class `container-fluid`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.closest -

```
var containerDiv = $(this).closest('.container-fluid');
```

From jquery closest page (http://goo.gl/tHBRx) -

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$div = $(this).parent();
```

to this:

```
$div = $('.container-fluid')[0];
```

Also, where is your input element?